# libSOIL Linker Error In XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, soil

So, I downloaded libSoil from https://github.com/smibarber/libSOIL and ran `make`, then `sudo make install` in Terminal. No errors, seemed to go fine.

But when I try and add libSOIL.dylib to the "Link Binary With Libraries" list in my XCode project, I get a linker error when I try to compile.

It says:

```
ld: library not found for -lSOIL
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I managed to install and link GLFW3 to my project without any problems, so I'm not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: You can provide an answer for your own questions, and even accept it (after a while), instead of marking in the title. That's rather helpful for future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem: my header search path was at /usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.1/include instead of /usr/local/include